# Unable to see Azure Function app "Application settings"

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In Azure function app Under settings I am unable to see "Application settings" and only able to see Runtime and general settings, please advise on this.

[image]

Tried reviewing Azure resource permissions , have contributor access like other developer but for me not showing Application settings option.

Comment: Can you please check here? And see if there is any similarity with your case? https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/8554

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application setting have been changed in Azure Portal, it is removed from `Configuration` option and New option have added as `Environment Variables`

To add Application Setting in your app you can use `Environment Variables`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Vivek for the answer. For only one user Application settings not sowing and environment variables showing and other users Showing Application settings and not showing environment variables. could you please share if you have reference link.

Comment: @Anand I am not sure why it is showing like that for one user but it does not affect application setting or web app in any way.

Comment: It is new update in azure. check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78126003/environment-variables-in-separate-menu-tab-on-azure-portal-app-service-settings

Comment: Thanks Vivek  for the update. Its helpful.